# Number is too long to be passed to Random() ?

Tags: java, random, numbers, long-integer, milliseconds

I'm trying to do

```
Random generator = new Random(1309233053284);
```

`Random` being `java.util.Random`

It says the number is too long, but why can `System.currentTimeMillis()` be passed to the constructor? It returns even bigger numbers.

`1309233053284` are milliseconds, if you're wondering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may have better luck with:

```
Random generator = new Random(1309233053284L);
```

In Java, all literal numbers are of type `int` unless otherwise specified.  To get your number interpreted as a `long`, you need to suffix it with 'L' (or alternately 'l', but that is difficult to distinguish from a '1', and therefore somewhat less clear).

Comment: Luck is nothing to do with it ... unless you use random monkeys with typewriters as software developers :-)

Comment: @Stephen - I have to disagree.  In my experience, software development is at least 90% luck.  For instance, if you get a library and a spec for the library, and the library actually follows what the spec says, then you are lucky.  If you compile your code for the first time and it does everything you want it to do, exactly as you want it to do it, then you are extremely lucky.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Random generator = new Random(1309233053284l);
```

You should specify it as a long.

If you call `new Random(1309233053284)`, it will use the constructor taking an `int` argument.  When you call `new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())`, it's using the constructur taking a `long` argument since `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a long.  To make it work, you should also specify `1309233053284` to be a long by adding the `l`.

Answer (score 0):

integer literals are `int` type by default. You need to add `f` for float, `d` for double and `L` for long. `L` is preferred to `l` as the later can look like `1`

e.g.

```
31 <= 31 as an int
3l <= looks like 31 but is 3 as a long.
31L <= 31 as a long.
311 <= is 311 as an int.
```